# How to read code from Azure DevOps Git repository contents from within Azure Data Factory v2

Tags: azure-devops, azure-data-factory

I am not trying to set up a git repository for my data factory -- rather I want my data factory to read some script files from already existing DevOps git repository. I didn't find any information about this. Mostly the information available is about how to set up git repository for ADFv2. There is also no connection type for Azure Dev Ops. Is there any workaround for this? My goal is to make my data factory more dynamic by fetching some scripts directly from DevOps git repo.

Comment: You can access you repository files over the **azure devops rest api** [trees](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/trees/get?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1). With a `GET` request of the file path you can read out the file content. Does that helps with you problem?

Comment: Little confused, what do you want is getting some script files from VSTS repos in ADF, but did not get connection with VSTS?

Comment: @MerlinLiang-MSFT what I need is to be able to access script files stored in git so my copy activity can refer to them and store in some storage blob somehow so that my HDInsight activity can use them. This is a workaround for HDInsightHive activity's inability to refer to hive scripts stored in git directly. It needs some storage blob path for this.

Comment: How did you manage to do this? I have the same issue right now. Thanks!